# How to configure conky in a tmux session?

Tags: console, conky, tmux

I want to have a custom footer in my `tmux` session with `conky`, my conky config as per conky official recommendation for `screen`:

```
conky.config = {
    out_to_x = false,
    out_to_console = true,
    total_run_times = 1
};
conky.text = [[${time %H:%M}|free space:${fs_free /}|$loadavg|free mem:$memeasyfree]]
```

`tmux` contains just one line in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g status-left "#(conky -i 1 -c ~/.conkyintmux) |"
```

but when I start `tmux`, the footer line reads

```
13:48|free0:bash*                                     "D830-2" 13:48 06-Sep-18
```

and without any `.tmux.conf` (not calling conky), it would read

[0] 0:bash*                                                 "D830-2" 13:53 06-Sep-18

Expected output:

```
13:48|free space:8.0GB|0.1 0.1 0.1|free mem:548MB|[0] 0:bash* "D830-2" 13:53 06-Sep-18
```

for a start to see if everything is as expected.

How can I change the behaviour of `tmux`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a tmux line such as

```
set-option -g status-left-length 50
```

as the default length is 10 characters, so your conky output is being heavily truncated.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what I expected, but certainly not a default length of 10 chars.